# Use Lodash to get object's values based on another object's truthy state

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to use Lodash to get the label for each animal with true value.

Expected result: `['DOG', 'CAT']`

Is there a way to do this without using `result.push`?.

How can I make `trueKeysLabel` gets the animal label from `labelList`?

```js
var result = [],
  labelList = {
    dog: 'DOG',
    cat: 'CAT',
    monkey: 'MONKEY'
  },
  animalList = {
    dog: true,
    cat: true,
    monkey: false
  }
trueKeys = _.filter(_.keys(animalList), function(key) {
  return animalList[key];
});

_.forEach(trueKeys, function(key) {
  result.push(_.get(labelList, key));
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried `_.get` but when it is used within `_.forEach`, `trueKeysLabel` equals the keys `['dog', 'cat']` instead of their values.

```
var trueKeysLabel = _.forEach(trueKeys, function(key) {
    return _.get(labelList, key);
});
```

Comment: It is considered good form to upvote any answers that have helped you, and / or to accept the most helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.filter()` to get the values from `labelList` that their key's value is `true` in `animalList`:

```js
var labelList = {
    dog: 'DOG',
    cat: 'CAT',
    monkey: 'MONKEY'
  },
  animalList = {
    dog: true,
    cat: true,
    monkey: false
  };

var result = _.filter(labelList, (v, k) => animalList[k]); 

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very nice, assuming ES6 is supported / valid!

Comment: @cale_b - thanks. In this case ES6 is not a must. It's easy to replace the arrow function, with a standard function.

Comment: Thank you! That's nice! I used function instead of `=>`
    `_.filter(labelList, function(value, key) {
        return animalList[key];
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain there's a handful of ways to do this, but the below does what you've asked using [_.pickBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pickBy), [_.identity](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#identity), [_.keys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keys), [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter), and [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#includes).

```js
var result = [],
  labelList = {
    dog: 'DOG',
    cat: 'CAT',
    monkey: 'MONKEY'
  },
  animalList = {
    dog: true,
    cat: true,
    monkey: false
  };

// pickBy will return an object of "truthy" values.
// keys then creates an array of the resultant object keys - ["dog", "cat"]
var keys = _.keys(_.pickBy(animalList, _.identity));

// filter will return only those values the predicate function returns truthy for
results = _.filter(labelList, function(val, key) {
  // return true if the key is in the list of "truthy" keys
  return (_.includes(keys, key));
});

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _.values()

```
_.forEach(trueKeys, function(key) {
      result.push(_.values(labelList[key]));
});
```

Comment: OP asked why it return keys instead of values

Comment: From question: _Is there a way to do this without using result.push?._

Comment: have tried _.get but when it is used within _.forEach, trueKeysLabel equals the keys ['dog', 'cat'] instead of their values.

Answer (score 0):

You also do not necessary need another library to do this. You can simply do `Object.entries` then `filter` and finally `map` to get the values:

```js
var labelList = { dog: 'DOG', cat: 'CAT', monkey: 'MONKEY' }, animalList = { dog: true, cat: true, monkey: false }

const r = Object.entries(labelList).filter(x => animalList[x[0]]).map(x => x[1])

console.log(r)
```